# Printing context root in loggers Log4j

Tags: log4j, config

I want to print loggers along with context root.

For example my loggers printing in console as below.

```
INFO  [MandatoryAdapter] Ends - validateData
```

Now I want as below.

```
INFO [APPLICATION_NAME] [MandatoryAdapter] Ends - validateData
```

Can any one help me on this regard.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have multiple apps, and each app has it's own log4j.properties file

we do something like this i.e. *hardcode* the web app name in the ConversionPattern

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSS}  <business> [-] %-5p %m \: %c-(%L) %n
```

Here `<business>` is the app name

**Further Reading**

[log4j properties for multiple webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549226/sharing-a-single-log4j-jar-file-in-tomcat5-between-multiple-webapps-with-separate)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Log4j's MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context, see [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC)) for this.

Essentially, your application sets the MDC thread-local variable to your application name, and the log4j logger then prints that out with each message.

If this is for a webapp, then you can set the MDC at the start of the request, and unset it when it finishes.

Comment: For a webapp using log4j2,does Thread-Context need to be set for every request or every thread?